# Unresolved differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

Why can't *Mathematica* solve this equation as stated?

```
DSolve[{z''[t]==(z'[t])^2+(z[t])^2-Sin[t]-1, z[0]==0,z[Pi/2]==1},z[t],t]
(* -> DSolve[{z''[t]==(z'[t])^2+(z[t])^2-Sin[t]-1, z[0]=0,z[Pi/2]=1},z[t],t] *)
```

Is there another way to solve it?

Comment: First of all, you have to replace the single equation marks `=` in your code with double equation marks `==`.

Comment: Even correcting for the ==, it still can't solve it: what makes you think it has a closed form solution? NDSolve gives an interpolating function as a solution.

Comment: If I use NDSolve I have the error: 
NDSolve :bvlin: The differential equation(s) and/or boundary conditions are \
not linear in the dependent variables. NDSolve requires linearity to compute \
the solution of a multipoint boundary value problem.

Comment: This works: `NDSolve[{z''[t] == z'[t]^2 + z[t]^2 - Sin[t] - 1, z[0] == 0, z[Pi/2] == 1}, z, {t, 0, Pi/2}]`.

Comment: Either, I get the same error

Comment: What version of *Mathematica* are you using, by any chance?

Comment: Mathematica 5.2

Comment: Ah, I see the problem now. For the others: to reproduce the behavior OP is describing, set `Method -> "Chasing"`.

Comment: But, then how can solve my equation?

Comment: Well, the problem is that the chasing method is [the only method available in *Mathematica* 5.2](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/Built-inFunctions/AdvancedDocumentation/DifferentialEquations/NDSolve/BoundaryValueProblems/Methods.html), and the other methods for BVPs only showed up in later versions. So, at the very least, you can't use `NDSolve[]` directly. You might want to try implementing shooting yourself...

Comment: "implementing shooting yourself" - a bit harsh :)

Comment: hahahahaha yes, I believe that it is a good option...

Comment: @cormullion That was pure genius. LOL

Comment: @cormullion, I suppose I could've suggested relaxation, but shooting is more effective for this matter... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Although you're using an outdated *Mathematica* version, the problem should be solvable as follows:

Instead of specifying two boundary conditions for the unknown function `z[t]` (one at $0$ and the other at $\pi/2$), start by imposing *initial conditions* at one end of the interval. In addition to the boundary condition you already have, a complete set of initial conditions for this second-order differential equation can be formed by additionally specifying the first derivative at that point.

Depending on the differential equation, one side of the `t` interval may be preferable to the other, depending on how sensitive the solution is to variations in the first derivative on each side. Here I'll choose the right-hand boundary to impose the initial conditions:

```
backwardSolution[finalSlope_?NumericQ] := z[t] /. First[
   NDSolve[{z''[t] == (z'[t])^2 + (z[t])^2 - Sin[t] - 1, 
     z[Pi/2] == 1, z'[Pi/2] == finalSlope},
    z, {t, Pi/2, 0}]]

boundaryValue[finalSlope_?NumericQ] := 
 backwardSolution[finalSlope] /. t -> 0

slope = finalSlope /. FindRoot[
   boundaryValue[finalSlope],
   {finalSlope, 1/2}
   ]

(* ==> -4.4082*10^-8 *)

Plot[Evaluate[backwardSolution[slope]], {t, 0, Pi/2}]
```

[image: plot]

This method works by imposing an arbitrary "final" slope at $t = \pi/2$, and then "chasing" the solution back to the initial time $t = 0$ in the function `backwardSolution[finalSlope]`. The function `boundaryValue` returns the resulting initial value of the solution. This value is supposed to match the first boundary condition, `z[0] == 0`, but initially it will not, because the final slope that we used was wrong. So the `FindRoot` step looks for the correct value of this `finalSlope`.

Once it is found, we call it `slope`, re-do the `backwardSolution[slope]` for this value and plot the resulting `InterpolatingFunction`. To impose a different boundary condition at `t = 0`, you could change the `boundaryValue` function by subtracting the desired boundary value from it (so that it returns zero when the boundary condition is satisfied).