# How could I define a function as the solution of equations in Mathematica?

Tags: equation-solving, functions

I have posed [a specific question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27100) yesterday but it may be too trivial to answer.

I think the question could be asked in a more general way so it is easier to answer. Then I could solve the original problem by myself.

Usually, we define a function as

```
F[x_] := x + 10
```

where the right-hand side is an expression.

Now, I would like define a function where the right-hand side is the solution of a set of equations. Like

```
optV[V_, r_, λ_, μ_, η_, σ_] := 
  V /. 
    FindRoot[{
      A V^θ[r, λ, μ, η, σ] h[V, c, r, λ, μ, η, σ] == V - c, 
      D[A*V^θ*h[V, c, r, λ, μ, η, σ], V] == 1
      }, 
      {A, 0}, {V, 1}]; 

a[V_, r_, λ_, μ_, η_, σ_] := 
  A /. 
    FindRoot[{
      A V^θ[r, λ, μ, η, σ] h[c, r, λ, μ, η, σ] == V - c, 
      D[A V^θ[r, λ, μ, η, σ]  h[V, c, r, λ, μ, η, σ], V] == 1
      }, 
      {A, 0}, {V,1}]
```

This may not be correct code, but I think you can understand my question from it. `optV` and `a` are both parameters for another final function which would be manipulated. So you could regard `optV` and `a` as intermediate parameters. So the solution of the set of equations, correspondingly `optV` and `a`, varies along with `c`, `r`, `λ`, `μ`, `η`, `σ`, which are parameters input for manipulating plot.

Comment: Since `NSolve[]` will return a list of lists, you'll likely want to put `Part[]` in there somewhere...

Comment: @0x4A4D http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V1bFr2SWP1I

Comment: @bel, FWIW: it's one of the songs I listen to after a hard day... precisely that medley.

Comment: Just yesterday I posted an answer [where this is illustrated](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27102/245). There are countless other answers on this site that do similar things. Maybe just searching for `NDSolve` will turn up other good examples.

Comment: you can easily do what you asked, eg.`f[a_] := x /. NSolve[{x + y == a, x^2 + y^2 == 1}, {x, y}]`. I cant understand what your intent is with those examples though. The arg x on input does what?

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom What I want is recaculating again for different parameters input. The original code is: 'code'optV[V_, r_, λ_, μ_, η_, σ_] := 
      V /. FindRoot[{A V^θ[r, λ, μ, η, σ]  h[V, c, r, λ, μ, η, σ] == V - c, 
             D[A*V^θ*h[V, c, r, λ, μ, η, σ], V] == 1}, {A, 0}, {V, 1}]; and I want the value of the function optV changes with parameters and optV is parameter for another function.

Comment: @george2079 I have edited the question and hope it is more clear.

Comment: Ok, I see now that my comments were not so useful. Anyway, why do you want to have a variable in your function that gets eliminated by the FindRoot? Do you want the function to remain constant if you change this variable?

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom I use FindRoot just because the equation set seems hard to be solved and if NSolve could make sense, NSolve would be no problem. I would like the function value changes with those parameters, thus it could be used as parameters for another function. The logic is: changing those parameters->different equation set->different solutions->different optV and a-> different F[V_] which is manipulated and optV and a are two of its parameters.

Comment: I can see that most of your arguments would change the resulting outcome of, say, `optV`. But still I don't see why you would want to have a parameter V as a function argument. For simplicity, consider again your other example. Note that `Solve[{x + y == 1, x^2 + y^2 == 1}, {x, y}]` gives you two solutions. Other than that there is no freedom to let the solution vary. Furthermore, I do not see what you would expect to happen if you "change x". I don't see how x could be a function argument. In the same way I don't see how V could be a function argument. Please explain

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom In fact, V is the only independent variable of F[V], which is the final function I would like to manipulate. That means F[V] is the y axis and V is the x axis. All other variables, including c, r, λ, μ, η, σ, optV, a, are all just parameters for F[V]. The only difference is that I would like c, r, λ, μ, η, σ to be the input parameters for manipulation and optV and a are intermediate parameters whose value are determined by c, r, λ, μ, η, σ via the equation sets. So several direct parameters, two indirect parameters whose values vary along with the direct parameters.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom If you would like to see my original question mentioned at the beginning of this question, you would know what it means.

Comment: Hmm lcet I think i am starting to understand :). Let me see..

Comment: @Icet Please post any reference to the model you're trying to simulate...

Comment: @RodLm Thank you very much for your concern. The model comes from chapter 5 of Dixit & Pindycks (1994), Investment under Uncertainty. If it is unavailable, Metcalf & Hassett(1995), Investment Under Alternative Return Assumptions: Comparing Random Walks and Mean Reversion, discusses this problem. Essentially, it is an optimal stopping problem where the underlying value assumes to follow OU process.

Comment: I assume all your arguments have numeric values -- You can not use a symbol that already has a value as an unknown in your equation.  Try using Vstar or something inside FindRoot.

Comment: @george2079 Yes, since values of parameters vary I define them as functions just like normal initialization does, and thus their values could be changed in manipulation. The problem is I don't know how to define the function if some parameters could not be presented as symbolic expressions but only numerical solutions of equations.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you right, here is the answer, but it is in a form of a more transparent example.

Let this

```
Clear[a,b];
eq=x^2 - b*x - 1 == 0
```

be an equation depending upon a parameter b with b>0. Let us define a=a[b] which is its smaller solution of the equation eq:

```
a[b_] := Solve[eq, x][[1, 1, 2]]
```

It seems that this (or something alike) is what you need. You can check that a is indeed a function of b by, say, plotting a[b]. Evaluate this:

```
Plot[a[b], {b, 0, 3}]
```

With some care one can do the same with the FindRoot statement:

```
Clear[a,b];
a[b_] := FindRoot[eq, {x, 0}][[1, 2]]
Plot[a[b], {b, 0, 3}]
```

Comment: While this works, I would be careful about explicitely making eq a function of `b`: 'eq[b_] = x^2 - b*x - 1 == 0' and I would force the definition of `a[b]` to take only numeric values: `a[b_?NumberQ]`. In this example it is fine, but you have to be careful of the order of evaluation when you are mixing both symbolic and numerical values.

Comment: Isn't it inefficient to call `Solve` every time the function `a` is evaluated? If you used `Set` instead of `SetDelayed`, the equation would only be solved once.

Comment: @nikie yes in this simple example.  There are however situations where you need to Solve (or especially NSolve ) for the specific value of the parameters.

Answer (score 2):

I will give an elaborate answer because I think this is an area where Mathematica really shines ;)

### Let me digress.

We know that, in general, an equation system defines a *set* of points as a function of the *parameters* in it. Namely, the set of variable assignments or valuations that make the equation true.

Thus an equation system can also be seen as a predicate $E(\vec x, \vec p)$ which defines the set of its solutions given the parameters $\vec p$:
$$sol(E, \vec p) := \{\vec x : E(\vec x, \vec p)\}$$

Note that "solving" an equation system, even for given parameter values (for example if you have no parameters) does not usually give a single value $\vec x$.

Now what does mathematica's Solve[E, {x1,...,xn}] (or NSolve) do? It gives a representation of this set in the form of a finite list of replacement rule sets,
$\{r_1, r_2, ..., r_n\}$.

Each $r_i$ contains rules of the form $x_{ij} \mapsto f_{ij}(\vec x', \vec p)$. Let $(\vec x)_i'$ be the sublist of $\vec x$ not appearing as an $x_{ij}$ (on the left hand side of a rule), $(\vec x)_i''$ be the others.
Then the ruleset $r_i$ defines a map $F_i$ with
$$(\vec x)_i'' := F_i((\vec x)_i', \vec p).$$
The set of solutions is then characterized as follows:
$$\vec x \in sol(E, \vec p) \iff \exists i\quad (\vec x)_i'' = F_i((\vec x)_i', \vec p).$$

---

### Turning this into a function

Ideally, we would want to get a function $G$ with

$$G(\vec p) := sol(E, \vec p)$$

Obviously, this is in general impossible because the set of solutions is infinite (sometimes not even countable).

But assume we knew $E$ has a finite amount of solutions for every fixed $\vec p$. Can we derive these from the output of Solve?

In general no, one because of the parameters $\vec C$ mathematica might add to describe the solution space and because we dont know which $(\vec x)_i'$ will not generate `Undefined` values with the functions we are given. And we get no explicit way of enumerating only valid candidates.

Still, if the $F_i$ are total in $(\vec x)_i'$ we might be able to leverage them to describe our solution space in a more explicit way.

In particular, we can ask Mathematica to give us the solution in 1 variable in terms of the parameters and the others, simply by 'solving' for that variable only. Using ParametricPlot and friends you can then visualize the solution.

---

### Wrap up

Lets assume you know that $(\vec x)_i'' = \vec x$ for all $r_i$, i.e. that all variables you care about have been explicitly solved for. Then the function 
$$f(\vec p) := \{F_1(\vec p), ...,F_n(\vec p)\}$$ can be defined in the following two ways in mathematica. (Let us write `{{x1, ...}*} = f[{p1, p2,...}]`).

#### 1. Solving the equation system once

If you know (or enforce) that `x1,...,p1,...` are undefined at the point of definition:

```
ClearAll[f, p1, p2, x1, x2];
(*Define f[{p1,...,pn}]. {x1,...,xn, p1,...,pn} must not be defined at this point \
for this to work*)
f[{p1_, p2_}] := Evaluate[{x1, x2} /. Solve[
     (*The equation system*)
     x2 == p1^2 + p1 && p2 == x1,
     {x1, x2}]];
(*Test*)
?f
f[{3, 4}]
```

Otherwise (namespace-clean version):

```
ClearAll[f];
(*Prepare f*)
Evaluate[Module[{x1, x2, p1, p2},
   f[params] = {p1, p2};
   f[variables] = {x1, x2};
   f[solutions] = f[variables] /.
     Solve[
      (*The equation system*)
      x2 == p1^2 + p1 && p2 == x1, f[variables]]]
  ];
(*Define f[{p1,...,pn}]*)
f[p_] := f[solutions] /. Rule @@@ Transpose@{f[params], p};
(*Test*)
?f
f[{3, 4}]
```

#### 2. Solving the equation system on every call

Namespace-dirty version -- `x1,...` must not be defined when *calling* f.

```
ClearAll[f, x1, x2];
(*When calling this function, x1,...,xn must be undefined*)
f[{p1_, p2_}] := {x1, x2} /. Solve[
    (*The equation system*)
    x2 == p1^2 + p1 && p2 == x1,
    {x1, x2}];
(*Test*)
?f
f[{3, 4}]
```

To make this clean, simply wrap the definition in a module:

```
ClearAll[f, x1, x2];
Module[{x1, x2},
  f[{p1_, p2_}] := {x1, x2} /. Solve[
      (*The equation system*)
      x2 == p1^2 + p1 && p2 == x1,
      {x1, x2}];
  ];
(*Test*)
?f
f[{3, 4}]
```

---

### Some more details

1. Note that the $F_i$ are in general partial functions. You may get

   `x -> ConditionalExpression[1, a > 0]`

   which is `Undefined` for certain values, try it:

   `ConditionalExpression[1, a > 0] /. {a -> 0}`
2. The above explanation makes it clear why `{}` denotes the empty set of solutions.

   And also why `{{}}` is the full dimensional set of solutions: In this case $(\vec x)_1' = \vec x$, $(\vec x)_1''$ is empty and the function $F_1$ returns nothing, thus $(\vec x)_1'' = F_1((\vec x)_1',\vec p)$ for any $\vec x$.
3. Sometimes Solve will introduce new parameters $\vec C$ in the solution. These parametrize the $F_i$ so that actually, implicitly, infinitely many $F_i$ are available to pick to construct a solution:

$$\vec x \in sol(E, \vec p) \iff \exists i\exists \vec C\quad (\vec x)_i'' = F_i((\vec x)_i', \vec p, \vec C).$$

4. Because "Solve gives generic solutions only. Solutions that are valid only when continuous parameters satisfy equations are removed" the picture I painted above is a bit too simple. Sometimes there will be solutions that Mathematica is well aware of but does not give because of this.
   It will generate ConditionalExpression with *inequalities* for parameters:

   `Solve[x^2 == a - b, x, Reals]`

   `{{x -> ConditionalExpression[-Sqrt[a - b], a > b]}, {x -> 
   ConditionalExpression[Sqrt[a - b], a > b]}}`

   but by default 'forgets' all solutions that would require an *equality* between parameters:

   `Solve[x == 0 && x^2 == a - b, x, Reals]`

   `{}`

   It will also generate solutions that are wrong for a finite set of parameter assignments:
   `Solve[x a == 1 , {x, y}]`
   `{{x -> 1/a}}`

   I don't see why you shouldn't always use `MaxExtraConditions -> All` which gives these solutions back:

   `Solve[x == 0 && x^2 == a - b, x, Reals, MaxExtraConditions -> All]`

   `{{x -> ConditionalExpression[0, a == b]}}`

   `Solve[x a == 1 , {x, y}, MaxExtraConditions -> All]`

   `{{x -> ConditionalExpression[1/a, a != 0]}}`